# How to make a recovery partition in Acer laptop?

Tags: windows, recovery-partition

By mistake I have deleted my recovery partition in Acer laptop. Can anybody help me to create a recovery partition?

Comment: What Kind of Acer Laptop? Did you make a recovery DVD when you first booted the Laptop?

Comment: Hi @Joe Taylor thanks for the reply.I am using Acer aspire 5542.That's the problem i din make recovery DVD.Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/11476-acer-hidden-recovery-partition-4.html) Forum:

---

If you can get a program like PartitionMagic or Partition Manager 7. These apps can create recovery disks and typically one of the neat features is "unhide" a partition. Do this and you could grab every off.

---

I MADE IT!!yes!now i can use ALT+F10 to enter the recovery options at the startup.it took some time but it worth it.i used an application available on the revocery cds which i have written before.i wuould explain more if anyone is interested to know more.
i also contacted acer and they said NAPP is not intended to be used by customers and it is jut used in repair centers.
so just one question exists.how can we make an image/backup of a customized windows?
i suggest that u dont convert your fat32 to ntfs using partition magic as i think doing using this made the recovery not to work.use with normal windows dos command prompt.i have done that before and no problem.so lets try and find how can we place an image of a customized winodws isntead of that available in the hidden partiotion.ok?

---

As a side note there is a CD used by Acer Engineers to restore the recovwery partition, amongst other things, called the NAPP CD. This is recommended for use by Acer Engineers only though. If you can find a download for your model then this could help you. I'll warn you though some sites charge for it and it doesn't seem easy to find a free one.